# Requested keys of a value that is not an object - React Native error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, react-redux

**posts:**

```
[
 { id:1, name:'post1', desc: 'post1 desc', parentId: 1 },
 { id:2, name:'post2', desc: 'post2 desc', parentId: 2 },
 { id:3, name:'post3', desc: 'post3 desc', parentId: 1  }
]
```

Posts coming from reducer. Have `mapStateToProps` and can print `this.props.posts` in console.

My Function:

```
getPosts = (idPost = 1) =>{
  const { posts } = this.props.posts
  return
      posts.filter(id => posts[id].parentId == idPost)
        .map((key, idx) => {
          const myPost = posts[key];
          return(
            <View>
               <Text>
                 { myPost.name }
               </Text>
            </View>
            )
        });  
};
```

Error: `Requested keys of a value that is not an object.` for line 1 of the function.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update 1**

```
getPostsNew = (namePost = 'post1) =>{
  const { posts } = this.props.posts

  return posts.map((key, idx) => {
    if (key.name == namePost) {
      return(
          <View>
             <Text>
               { key.name }
             </Text>
          </View>
      )
    } else {
      return null
    }
  });         
};
```

Comment: shouldn't it be const { posts } = this.props; instead of this.props.posts? Also posts.filter will give you each post in the callback not just the id. check your filter function also. same goes for map function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify your code as below to fix this issue:

```
getPosts = (idPost = 1) =>{
    const { posts } = this.props.posts

    return posts.map((key, idx) => {
      if (key.parentId === 1) {
          return(
              <View>
                 <Text>
                   { key.name }
                 </Text>
              </View>
          )
      } else {
          return null
      }
      });         
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.getPosts(1)}
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I tried it and wrapped { key.name } in  `<Text>` but nothing is showing. I don't see any error but no data either.

Comment: I'm calling it as `{ this.getPosts() }`

Comment: It works! Thanks a ton! What was wrong with my original function?

Comment: Happy to help you. The filter function won't work properly that way and you should notice that the map function iterate the array and the first argument (`key` in this case) of map function is the current object.

Comment: One last question. What would I do if the `idPost` is a `string` and a `number`? It will be either of the two for posts.

Comment: How can I create the `(key.parentId === idPost)`? With 2 `==` or keep it at `===` ?